# Removing everything after and including "[" from a string in R

Tags: r, regex

I am attempting to modify the column names of some data set. Each column is named similar to this string:

```r
Patient Age [70: Age]
```

First, I would like to remove  `[70:Age]`, so that I just have `Patient Age` and then I would like to replace all instances of spaces in the string with underscores.

I know how to replace the spaces with underscores with `gsub()` but I can't quite figure out how to remove everything after  `[...`.

I keep getting an "*`invalid regular expression`*" error since regex is expecting a `]` as well.

If you can help me with the correct syntax please let me know.

I know that the code below removes the punctuation but I do not want the " 70 Age" in the column name

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", names(full_data)[1])
[1] "Patient Age 70 Age"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using

```r
x <- "Patient Age [70: Age]"
trimws(gsub("(?:\\[[^][]*]|\\s)+", "_", x), whitespace="_")
# => [1] "Patient_Age"
```

Here,

- `(?:\[[^][]*]|\s)+` - matches one or more occurrences of

  - `\[[^][]*]` - a `[`, then any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` char
  - `|` - or
  - `\s` - a whitespace char

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g0psJ7/1) and [an R demo](https://ideone.com/9S7WJV).

The matches are replaced with `_`. Since there can be leading/trailing `_` in the resulting string, you can trim them off with `trimws`.

Comment: trimws() works perfectly. Also, Thank you for the explanation of the syntax!

Comment: what if I also needed to just cut out instances of say "/" or "-" from the string before removing white space?

Comment: @DanielRodriguez I understand you mean to replace `/` and `-` with underscores? Then use `(?:\\[[^][]*]|[/[:space:]-])+` regex

Answer (score 4):

We can just use `trimws` and `chartr` from `base R`

```
chartr(" ", "_", trimws(x, whitespace = "\\s*\\[.*"))
#[1] "Patient_Age"
```

#### data

```
x <- "Patient Age [70: Age]"
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use a nested `sub` operation:

```
sub("\\s", "_", sub("\\s\\[.*?\\]", "", x))
```

The first `sub` (on the right) deletes the whitespace before the `[...]` expression as well as the `[...]` expression itself, the second `sub` (on the left) replaces the remaining white space(s) with `_`.